# Unable to modify data on i-Series DB2 from .NET

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ibm-midrange, data-access, db2-connect

I am having an application in .NET that uses Entity Framework 4. I am using the DB2/400 as my application backend. I am able to make queries and read successfully from the database.
However on any other operation (such as insert/update/delete), I am getting errors.
 I found the answer at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14222306 which stated that my DB2 client driver was not configured for transactions.
However, under /sqllib/cfg folder there is no db2cli.cfg file present (or anywhere else on my computer)
Also, I am able to modify the tables from the green screen/java application.
Here is one of my methods :

```
using (var context = new Data.SchemaEntity()) {
            string sql = "select * from schemaname.tablename where FLD='V2'";
            var rows = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<CUST>(sql, null);
            CUST c = rows.First(); // This is giving me the correct data

            if(c.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
                context.CUSTS.Attach(c);
            context.CUSTS.DeleteObject(c);

            context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

My questions are :

- Should I go for another versions/ installation of DB2 express-C that
  installs the .NET driver/provider.
- Can I use any other approach for
  data persistence within the entity framework (for example in
  jpa/hibernate we can use explicit Transactions).

If you've got any ideas (That I can possibly try, please do mention here)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much luck with using entity framework with the i. Typically, I have just used the ADO.NET driver from IBM i Access. Sorry I don't have a better answer for you. I have been looking for months for a EF driver for the i.

Comment: Still searching? I am also bound to iSeries and building "fat" ado.net methods for a simple select...

Comment: Yep, still searching. There is one package you can buy that looks like it _might_ work with EF, but I haven't seen 100% one way or another.

Comment: i found my solution..i am using DAPPER micro-ORM Check it out..If you want EF provider you have to go with DBConnect with is a payware product of IBM